# Overriding operator*() of iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

Say that I have some user-defined complex struct, like

```
struct usrStruct{
     double a;
     T1 b;
     T2 c;
     /* and so on...*/
}
```

which is used as a basic element for a std::vector, std::list or anything *iterable*..

Say that the `std::vector<usrStruct>` is passed to a function of mine through iterators

```
  template<class InputIterator>  
  T myFoo( InputIterator first, InputIterator last ){ /*...*/ }.
```

**Q**: Is there a standard way to override `operator*()` of the `InputIterator`, (in this case of `std::vector<usrStruct>::iterator` ) so that  `myFoo` just  *interacts* with the member `a`?

i.e., so that

```
  *first == (*first).a;
```

and thus `myFoo` works *orthogonally* with respect to the whole definition of `usrStruct`?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, according to wikipedia as found: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B   you can overload the dereference operator, but to do how you want it to is most likely pragmatic

Comment: It’s important to realise that if that were possible it would break the interface contract of the container/iterator. And that in turn would make your object unusable with a lot of algorithms (both in the standard library and third party libraries).

Comment: you mean because of the fact that  `iterator_traits` stuff would break, for instance?

so, if I would like to `std::copy` a `vector<usrStruct>` to a `vector<double>`, I have no choices than doing as @benjamin says. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that.  You can make your struct implicitly convertible to a double (via `operator double`).  Or you can allow direct comparisons by overloading `operator==(usrSruct,double)` and/or `operator==(double,usrStruct)`.

Comment: Thank you. 

my final aim, indeed, is to be independent even on the `double`. 
The member `a` in the user struct can be of any type (although in a finite set) and `myFoo` will call specific template function.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new `iterator` that based on `vector::iterator` and reflect it as double values and it is really simple:

```
template< class BaseIterator >
struct custom_iterator :
    std::iterator<std::iterate_traits<BaseIterator>::iterator_category, double>
{
public:
    typedef std::iterator<std::iterate_traits<BaseIterator>::iterator_category, double>
        base_t;
    typedef typename base_t::reference reference;
public:
    custom_iterator( BaseIterator it ) : m_it( it ) {}
public:
    reference operator*() const {
        return my_it->a;
    }
    custom_iterator& operator++ () {++m_it; return *this;}
    custom_iterator operator++ (int) {
        custom_iterator tmp( *this );
        ++m_it;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==( custom_iterator const& rhs ) const {
        return m_it == rhs.m_it;
    }
private:
    BaseIterator m_it;
};
```

And now you can use it as `myFoo( custom_iterator(v.begin()), custom_iterator(v.end()) )`

Comment: Indeed, my concern here was about design. I.e. is it a good idea to do so?

Comment: it depend on your need, using new `iterator` you can pass your `struct` to every function that work with iterators of type `double`.