# Override only operator*() of iterator of a custom datastructure

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, iterator

I have an array class `MyArray` with `MyArray`.
For simplicity, this is the whole code.  It works OK.

### Current code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T> class MyArray;
template<class T>class MyIterator{
    public: int index=0;
    public: MyArray<T>* myArray;
    public: MyIterator<T> operator++(){
        index++;
        return *this;
    }
    public: T& operator*(){
        return myArray->database[index];
    }
    public: friend bool operator!=(MyIterator<T> b,MyIterator<T> c){
        return b.index!=c.index;
    }
};
template<class T>class MyArray{
    public: T database[5];
    public: MyArray(){
        database[2]=3; //just fill with something to test
    }
    public: MyIterator<T> begin(){
        MyIterator<T> r;  r.index=0; r.myArray=this;
        return r;
    }
    public: MyIterator<T> end(){
        MyIterator<T> r;  r.index=5; r.myArray=this;
        return r;
    }
};
```

Here is its usage :-

```
int main() {
    MyArray<int> test;
    for(int ele:test){
        std::cout<<ele<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Problem / requirement

I have **specific** classes, let's say their names are `B` and `C`.
I have **a converter** from `B` to `C` named `convertBToC(B)`.

Now, I want a new datastructure (named `MyArray2`) that :-

- act mostly like `MyArray<B>` ....
- except that function `operator*()` of `MyArray2`'s iterator **return `C` instead of `B`**
- the `C` that is returned, convert from `B` using `convertBToC(B)`.

This is the usage that I wished for (`#1`) :-

```
MyArray2 test;
//test.push_back(B());  //used like "MyArray<B>"
for(C c:test){          //"C", not "B"
    .... logic about "c" ....  
}
```

The above code would work as if I call it like :-

```
MyArray<B> arr;   
for(B& b: arr){
    C c= convertBToC(b);   //<-- I want to hide this line
    .... logic about "c" .... 
}
```

**Question:** How to code `MyArray2`?

### **Criteria**

I want a solution that :- (sorted by priority)

- efficient (not use `std::function` and its family)
- not refer to `MyIterator` directly (because `MyIterator` is an internal class)
- cute (low amounts of statement/line, readable)
- minimum change to `MyArray<T>` (if any)

The most related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880515/overriding-operator-of-iterators), but it mentions about `std::vector`.

## My poor solutions

### Solution 1 (2x inheritance)

Create 2 classes :-

- `MyArray2` derived from `MyArray<B>`
  **Override:** `begin()` or `end()` - return `MyIterator2`.
- `MyIterator2` derived from `MyIterator<B>`
  **Override:** `operator*()` - return `C` (using `convertBToC()`).

**Disadvantage:**

- Dirty - I have to create 2 classes just to override only 1 function.
- `MyArray2.h` code contains the word `MyIterator<T>`.

### Solution 2 (lambda)

Create only 1 class :-

- `MyArray2` derived from `MyArray<B>`
  **new function:** `iterate()` :-

Here is the draft of `iterate()` :-

```
template<typename F> MyArray2::iterate( F lamdbaFunction ){
    for(B b: MyArray<B>){
         C c= convertBToC(b);
         lamdbaFunction(c);
    }
}
```

The usage have to be changed from `#1` to be ...  (`#2`)

```
MyArray2 arr;   
auto lambdaF=[&](C c){     
    .... logic about "c" .... 
}
arr.iterateElement(lambdaF);
```

**Disadvantage**

- It sometimes destroy readability. (Lambda sometimes harder to read)
- It limits coding style. (Sometimes, I prefer range-based loop.)

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? You have a `MyArray2<int>` and when you access an element you get a `string`? This is way too clever, just use `convertBtoC(arr[i])` instead.

Comment: @nwp   Thank! You understand the question.   Yes, I can do an easy way like you suggest.  However, I want this feature for encapsulation - in a certain part of code that *really* need this encapsulation.  In such case, the caller usually just wants to call range-based loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to use Boost range adaptors, specifically [`boost::adaptors::transformed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html).

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
...

MyArray<B> test;
for(C ele : test | boost::adaptor::transformed(convertBToC)) {
    // something...
}
```

Judge how much of an improvement it is yourself. Maybe better put the `operator|` call inside a new `MyArray`'s member function.

Comment: Wow cool, I will look into boost's code.  I will need time to investigate how it implement!

Comment: This could also be done without boost and without the silly `operator |`, but the core idea of having an external thing that does the conversion without changing `MyArray` is nice and composable.

Comment: Yes, I guess all it needs is a conversion constructor.

Comment: @LogicStuff If it doesn't disturb you too much, may you take a look at [a follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360760/create-my-own-iterator-adapter-dangling-pointer-when-create-adapter-of-adapte), please?   Just only take a look would be really appreciated.